# Retrieve the divs appended by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I append some `<div>` elements dynamically. Now I want fetch the array of items that I appended, however this code doesn't work. It just returns `0`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").append("<div>div1</div>");
  $("#test").append("<div>div3</div>");
  $("#test").append("<div>div2</div>");

  $("#test").each(function(v) {
    console.log(v); // I want to sort the items....
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: There's really two questions here. To loop over the `div` you append use `$('#test div').each(...`. Although note that the first argument of the handler function is the index of the current element in the collection, which is why your result is `0`. Use `this` instead to actually reference the element itself. Next, to sort them use `sort()`. However it makes a lot more sense to append them in the order required.

Comment: `$("#test").each` <-- that is not selecting the divs you added `$("#test > . div").each` would

Comment: i would add a special class or attribute to denote precisely which elements were created.

Comment: "*It just returns 0*" - you're using `$().each(function(index, element) ...` - as there's only one element in the collection `$("#test")` you get one log of `0` (the first index, zero-based).

Comment: *"Retrieve divs appended"* - my first thought would be to use `.appendTo` instead - then you already have them and don't need to "retrieve" them.

Comment: I understood I have two mistakes about variables and selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DOMNodeInserted` event to call function when new element append to parent:

```js
 var arr =[];
 $("#test").on("DOMNodeInserted",function() {
     //console.log(event.target);
     arr.push(event.target);
  });
  $("#test").append("<div>div1</div>");
  $("#test").append("<div>div3</div>");
  $("#test").append("<div>div2</div>");

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div>exception</div>
</div>
```

To sort array:

```js
var arr = [];
$("#test").on("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    //console.log(event.target);
    arr.push(event.target);
    arr.sort(function(f, n) {
        return $(f).text().replace(/div(\d+)$/, "$1") - $(n).text().replace(/div(\d+)$/, "$1");
    });

});
$("#test").append("<div>div1</div>");
$("#test").append("<div>div3</div>");
$("#test").append("<div>div2</div>");

console.log(arr); //sorted array contains object HTMLDivElement(s)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Compare textContent of div elements in function

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and sort function too.

Answer (score 0):

@whitebear, Check if following code works for you:

```
$(function() {

    $("#test").append("<div>div1</div>");
    $("#test").append("<div>div3</div>");
    $("#test").append("<div>div2</div>");

    $("#test").find('div').each(function(i, v){
      console.log(v); // I want to sort the items....
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see following answer :)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").append("<div>div1</div>");
  $("#test").append("<div>div3</div>");
  $("#test").append("<div>div2</div>");

  $("#test").children("div").each(function() {
      //Each element of child/appended child
      var el = $(this);
      //Console content of each children
      console.log(el.html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user `$.each` to iterate loop over the div's in `#test`
Try below mentioned code:

```
$.each($("#test div", function(){
 console.log($(this))
})
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the most likely reason is a) you have a typo and b) OP is already using `$(selector).each...`.   The issue is with the selector, changing to `$.each` would not fix OPs code.  You've added in `#test div` but not included this in your details - so it looks like you've just changed `$().each` to $.each($()` which has no impact.